# MySQL: refind groups of user from group description

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a problem to find the group membership for users. (yes it's not very clear like that)
For example:
I have 2 table:
- one contains a user list with their permission:

```
userId | permission
-------|-----------
1      | build
1      | play
1      | jump
2      | build
2      | jump
2      | run
3      | drink
3      | build
4      | run
```

-the second table contain the group and him permisson:

```
groupId | permission
--------|-----------
G1      | build
G1      | jump
G2      | play
G2      | jump
G3      | drink
G3      | run
G4      | drink
G5      | build
```

My goal is to find all the groups that the user can have:

```
userId | groupId
-------|-----------
1      | G1
1      | G2
1      | G5
2      | G1
2      | G5
3      | G4
3      | G5
```

I have created a request to find which users belong to the group but I can not do this for all my groups (I have more than 1000 group in my datasets):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId
FROM (
       SELECT userId, count(*) AS nbData
       from table_a
       WHERE permission in (
         SELECT permission
         from table_b
         where groupId = 'g1'
       )
       group by userId
     ) as t
where nbData = (SELECT count(*) from table_b where groupId = 'g1');
```

An user belongs to a group if he has all the permission of the group. And the goal is to find every group of each user

Comment: I'm not completely understanding your expected results given your sample data.  Are you looking to return only users who have all groups?  Or just at least one?  If the later, a simple `join` will do the trick...

Comment: This isn't related to `cross-join`, that's a cross product with no relationship between the tables. And it also doesn't seem related to `group-by`, since you're not aggregating in any way.

Comment: @sgeddes It doesn't seem to be a simple join, as that produces rows not in his desired results.

Comment: ok I have complet the question

Comment: Are you looking to return only users who have all groups? The objectif is not to find a users. the goal is to find which user is in which group (a user can be in 0 group or more. In this cas user 1 is in 3 groups and user 4 havn't group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have duplicates in either table, you can join the tables together on permissions and aggregate:

```
select up.userId, gp.groupId
from user_permissions up join
     group_permissions gp
     on up.permission = gp.permission
group by up.userId, gp.groupId
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from group_permissions gp2
                   where gp2.groupId = gp.groupId
                  );
```

The user is in the group if all the permissions for the group match.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.userId,
    b.groupId
FROM
    table_a a
    JOIN table_b b 
        ON a.permission = b.permission
```

Comment: in your case the user 2 is in group G3 but the user 2 can't drink

Comment: Your result:
userId, groupID|
1,g1 | 
1,g5 | 
1,g2 | 
2,g1 | 
2,g5 | 
2,g2 | 
2,g3 | 
3,g3 | 
3,g4 | 
3,g1 | 
3,g5 | 
4,g3

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_permissions;

CREATE TABLE user_permissions
(user_id INT NOT NULL
,permission VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,permission)
);

INSERT INTO user_permissions VALUES
(1,'build'),
(1,'play'),
(1,'jump'),
(2,'build'),
(2,'jump'),
(2,'run'),
(3,'drink'),
(3,'build'),
(4,'run');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS group_permissions;

CREATE TABLE group_permissions
(group_id INT NOT NULL
,permission VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(group_id,permission)
);

INSERT INTO group_permissions VALUES
(101,'build'),
(101,'jump'),
(102,'play'),
(102,'jump'),
(103,'drink'),
(103,'run'),
(104,'drink'),
(105,'build');

SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
              , g.group_id 
           FROM user_permissions u 
           JOIN group_permissions g 
             ON g.permission = u.permission -- groups that users potentially belong to
           LEFT 
           JOIN 
              ( SELECT DISTINCT x.user_id
                              , y.group_id 
                           FROM user_permissions x 
                           LEFT 
                           JOIN group_permissions y 
                             ON y.permission = x.permission 
                           LEFT 
                           JOIN group_permissions z 
                             ON z.group_id = y.group_id 
                           LEFT 
                           JOIN user_permissions a 
                             ON a.user_id = x.user_id 
                            AND a.permission = z.permission 
                          WHERE a.user_id IS NULL
              ) n -- groups that users don't belong to (this could be much simpler ;-) )
             ON n.user_id = u.user_id 
            AND n.group_id = g.group_id 
          WHERE n.user_id IS NULL;
+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |      101 |
|       1 |      105 |
|       1 |      102 |
|       2 |      101 |
|       2 |      105 |
|       3 |      105 |
|       3 |      104 |
+---------+----------+
```